# SQL Query to fetch employee whose salary increased after November

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Suppose we have a table named PMT,

Table contains three columns `i.e (ID, Pmt_Date and Pmt_Amount)`,

Here the `ID` column is the `Primary Key`.

Now we have payment amount along with Payment dates for four months for each employee 
`i.e Nov 2018,Dec 2018, Jan 2018 and Feb 2018.`

Query should pull the ID of all the employees whose salary have CHANGED(either increased or decreased) after November 2018.

Comment: And how many children does the employee have?  That's an old joke.  You have said nothing about where `salary` is stored.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Is there a reason why MySQL and SQL Server (MSSQL) are both tagged here? Both have other SQL dialets (features) on top off ANSI SQL.

Comment: Considering the OP says they're using MySQL Workbench, we'll go with the ***assumption*** they're using MySQL.

Comment: Also [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ID Column contains Id of employee,Pmt_Date contains Date on which Payment was issued and Pmt_Amount contains Salary/Amount that was recieved.

Comment: Please suggest sql queries that might work or logic which may work are also welcomed. Thanks

Comment: You should put your actual schema, sample data and expected result in text format. As it will be better than what your are trying to say in statements here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
create table #PMT(
ID Int Identity(1, 1) not null primary Key, 
empCd varchar(5), 
Pmt_Date varchar(10), 
Pmt_Amount decimal(18, 2))

Insert into #PMT (empCd, Pmt_Date, Pmt_Amount) values
('A001', 'Nov 2018', 10000),('A001', 'Dec 2018', 10000),('A001', 'Jan 2018', 10000),('A001', 'Feb 2018', 10000),
('A002', 'Nov 2018', 15000),('A002', 'Dec 2018', 15000),('A002', 'Jan 2018', 15000),('A002', 'Feb 2018', 15000),
('A003', 'Nov 2018', 25000),('A003', 'Dec 2018', 15000),('A003', 'Jan 2018', 22000),('A003', 'Feb 2018', 23000),
('A004', 'Nov 2018', 55000),('A004', 'Dec 2018', 45000),('A004', 'Jan 2018', 46000),('A004', 'Feb 2018', 47000),
('A005', 'Nov 2018', 48000),('A005', 'Dec 2018', 45000),('A005', 'Jan 2018', 46000),('A005', 'Feb 2018', 47000)

Select distinct emp.empCd, emp.Name
from #PMT p
inner join #emp emp on p.empCd = emp.empCd
where p.Pmt_Amount not in (

Select Pmt_Amount from #PMT 
inner join #emp on #PMT.empCd = #emp.empCd
where Pmt_Date <> 'Nov 2018'

) and p.Pmt_Date = 'Nov 2018'
```

Here the output will be as shown below.

```
empCd   Name
-----------
A003    C
A004    D
A005    E
```

Here in output A and B has not come because his salaries are same as in Nov 2018. You can change the data type as date instead of Varchar and apply `Month()` and `Year()` with date to get month and year of payment also.

To get the employee who has got their salary same as in other month you need to use just `in` operator instead of `not in` operator as shown below.

```
Select distinct emp.empCd, emp.Name
from #PMT p
inner join #emp emp on p.empCd = emp.empCd
where p.Pmt_Amount in (

Select Pmt_Amount from #PMT 
inner join #emp on #PMT.empCd = #emp.empCd
where Pmt_Date <> 'Nov 2018'

) and p.Pmt_Date = 'Nov 2018'
```

You can find live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/VWABMT67925).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select p.id from payments p
where exists (
  select 1 from payments 
  where 
  id = p.id and 
  month(pmt_date) = 11 and year(pmt_date) = 2018 and 
  pmt_amount <> p.pmt_amount
)
where p.pmt_date >= '2018-12-01'
```

This will get the ids of the employees whose salary has changed after November,
 meaning from `'2018-12-01'`, compared to the salary of November.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID
from PMT
where Pmt_Date => '2018-11-01'
group by ID
having count(distinct Pmt_Amount) > 1
```

If `Pmt_Amount` has changed since `2018-11-01`, The number of distinct payments (`count(distinct Pmt_Amount)`) will be more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `salary` WHERE `Pmt_Date` > '2019-05-30' AND `Pmt_Amount` <> (SELECT AVG(Pmt_Amount) AS avg FROM `salary` WHERE `Pmt_Date` <= '2019-05-30')
```

[image]

I used April month instead of nov